# Missing characters in a combination of string and integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

So far, I have created the one that returns missing string character. Can we also mix it with integers? For example:

Input: `"3629aghrjlsbwofhe"`

Output: `"014578bcdikmnpqtuvxyz"`

Current code for alphabet string:

```py
def missingCharacters(Str):
    
    MAX_CHAR = 26
    
    x = [False for i in range(MAX_CHAR)]
    

    for i in range(len(Str)):
        if (Str[i] >= 'a' and Str[i] <= 'z'):
            x[ord(Str[i]) - ord('a')] = True
        
    result = ""
 
    for i in range(MAX_CHAR):
        if (x[i] == False):
          result += chr(i + ord('a'))
        
    return result
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do the following, using some `string` utils and a conditional generator expression:

```
from string import digits, ascii_lowercase

def missingCharacters(s):
    # if s is long, this will make the repeated membership test O(1)
    # s = set(s)   
    return "".join(c for c in digits + ascii_lowercase if c not in s)

missingCharacters("3629aghrjlsbwofhe")
# '014578cdikmnpqtuvxyz'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this function is for some assignment for your college or company. This could be a naive solution for your problem to show our approach in a clear manner. Just a list update on your code for digits.

```
def missingCharacters(Str):
    
    MAX_CHAR = 26
    
    x = [False for i in range(MAX_CHAR)]
    y = []
    

    for i in range(len(Str)):
        if (Str[i] >= 'a' and Str[i] <= 'z'):
            x[ord(Str[i]) - ord('a')] = True
        if (Str[i].isdigit()):
            y.append(int(Str[i]))
        
    
    result = "".join(str(x) for x in range(10) if x not in y)

    for i in range(MAX_CHAR):
        if (x[i] == False):
          result += chr(i + ord('a'))
        
    return result
```